# python - remove text that is inside certain tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a string with "code" tags in it and I want to remove these tags and everything inside these tags.  For example,

```
"hello how are <code>this is my code</code> you"
```

becomes

```
"hello how are you"
```

I am pretty sure that BeautifulSoup is the right tool for the job, however I have looked at the documentation and I cannot figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Just `<code>` tags or all tags?

Comment: If you don't have nested tags and no really difficult structure, regex sometimes work for this.

Comment: right just <code> tags

Comment: Kaggle's facebook contest? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy with `Tag.extract()`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> s = "hello how are <code>this is my code</code> you"
>>> soup = BS(s)
>>> codetags = soup.find_all('code')
>>> for codetag in codetags:
...    codetag.extract()
>>> print soup
hello how are  you
```

Comment: I'm getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'

Comment: @user1893354: That would happen if there is no `<code>` tag in the string.

Comment: Sorry.  I would be using this code for multiple strings, some having the tags some not.

Comment: Also, this would remove only the *first* tag if there were multiple in the string

Comment: @DavidRobinson Having re-read the question, it does say `"code" tags`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: It looks like this solution adds <html> and <body> tags that were not there before.  I do not want this

Comment: @user1893354 Yes, that's part of `BeautifulSoup`. You can simply do `print soup.find('body').text`

Comment: @user1893354 Great to hear!